# Covering the sphere with an approximately planar grid

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, spherical-geometry, triangulations

Consider a triangulation of a radius $R$ sphere into $n$ triangles.  Must $Ω(\sqrt n)$ triangles have $Ω(1)$ relative difference from being an equilateral triangle of area $4πR^2/n$?   ($Ω$ is from the [Big O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).)

Equivalently, is it true that $∃ε>0 \, ∀n>20$ every triangulation of a sphere into $n$ triangles must have at least $ε\sqrt{n}$ edges longer than $(1+ε)s$ or shorter than $(1−ε)s$, where $s$ is the side-length of an equilateral triangle that covers $1/n$ of the area of the sphere?

This problem is probably already solved somewhere, but here is what I have:

- A stronger version of the conjecture is that for all small enough $ε$ and all $n>1/ε$, we must have at least $C\sqrt{n/ε}$ edges as above (for some constant $C>0$ independent of $ε$).
- For $n>20$, not all triangles can be equilateral.  However, starting with the icosahedron, we can triangulate such that all angles are above 54° and all edge lengths are within a factor of 1.26 of each other (as commented by Matt F.).  With some effort, we can even ensure (perhaps with a bit worse lengths/angles) that all triangles have approximately the same area.
- Without the area restriction, all but $O(1)$ triangles can be, within a factor of $1+ε$, equilateral (use a triangulation (of a combinatorial sphere) with $O(1)$ 'defects', and then apply a conformal mapping; note: many triangles will have $o(R^2/n)$ areas there).
- Approximately equilateral triangles have a locally unique triangulation topology (assuming no hinge vertices), allowing a grid-based local coordinate system and a global coordinate chart, with (under the coordinates) isometric connections.
- For a 'sturdy' simply-connected region and similar triangle sizes, a single coordinate system gives correct distances within a factor of $1+ε$ or so (hence "approximately planar").  However, a long thin strip can easily bend.
- A nonsimply connected region can have topological defects. A topological defect is characterized by a dislocation and holonomy (which affects how dislocation propagates); orientation is preserved for us.
- If all defects have zero holonomy, then the dislocations are additive, and due to the intrinsic curvature (for example, circles on spheres have low perimeters for their areas), we need $Ω(\sqrt n)$ coordinate dislocation (assuming similar triangle sizes) to cover a large convex area of the sphere.
- Nonzero defect holonomy, being quantized, ordinarily gives many distorted (or wrong-sized) triangles, but I do not have a simple characterization.

I conjecture a positive answer, and that dealing with the distortions from the ideal grid leads to fractal-like optimal asymptotic solutions for a number of optimization problems on the sphere, including maximum sphericity, minimal length equal area partitions of the sphere, and the [Thomson problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem) (classical electrons on a sphere).  I discuss this in detail in the [Asymptotic optimal sphericity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391261/asymptotic-optimal-sphericity) question.  A positive answer here implies $1 - \frac{5 \sqrt{3} π}{27n} - Θ(n^{-3/2})$ maximum sphericity for polyhedra with $n$ faces.

Comment: What is "relative difference from being an equilateral triangle"?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin A triangle has $O(ε)$ relative difference from being equilateral iff its angles are $60°±O(ε)$.  (And $O(ε)$ relative difference from area $A$ means having area $(1±O(ε))A$.)  The constant factors are not important here.

Comment: Just to make sure --- you want roughly $\sqrt{n}$ triangles sufficiently far from being equilateral?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Correct (sufficiently far from being area $4πR^2/n$ equilateral).

Comment: @MattF. Even if we get similar areas there, the triangles are presumably not going to be close to equilateral.

Comment: If you 1) inscribe an icosahedron, 2) divide each edge into $n$ pieces, 3) draw lines between the interior points of neighboring edges, 4) project the resulting mesh onto the sphere, then you get a triangulation with $20n^2$ faces, and the maximum ratio of sidelengths is bounded by the ratio of the circumradius and inradius, which is $\sqrt{3}\tan(\pi/5)=\sqrt{3(5-2\sqrt{5})}=1.26$

Comment: I deleted my old comment and old answer when I realized I could outdo them both with the above comment. So now would be a good time to add a more precise version of the question: *Is it true that $\forall\epsilon\,\exists k\,\exists m\,\forall n\ge m$, any triangulation of a sphere with $n$ faces has at least $k\sqrt{n}$ edges longer than $(1+\epsilon)s$ or shorter than $(1−\epsilon)s$, where $s$ is the side-length of an equilateral triangle which covers $1/n$ of the area of the sphere?*

Comment: @MattF.  Thank you.  I edited the question; it should look much better now.

Comment: Your argument about dislocations reminded me of the theory that Bowick, Nelson, and Travesset (https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9911379 as well as follow ups) described for using elasticity theory to give a continuum limit description of the way dislocations and disclinations interact in a 2D crystal on a curved surface.